# What happens if I instantiate an object within its own constructor?

Tags: object, constructor, client, call, instantiation

```
//object class
public class test
{
    public test()
    {
        test t1 = new test();
    }
}

//client class in same folder
public class Client
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        test t = new test();
    }
}
```

Does this just make infinite empty test objects?
What happens to the computer memory space/RAM do things just get deleted as more objects are continuously created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial reasoning is correct: you get an "infinite" number of test objects. Each object creates a new one. The constructor for the first object created (by main) never finishes.

However, the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) has a limit on the stack size. Every time the constructor calls the next constructor, an entry is pushed onto the stack. Within a short amount of time, you'll get a stack overflow exception and your program will be terminated.